# Weak-minded vs Unintelligent?

Tags: meaning

My sense, despite the literal interpretation one might make, is that stupidity and being weak-minded are different but possibly related. I think weak-minded might mean easily swayed which I think is not a characteristic of intelligence.

At the same time, being stubborn, which I think might be the opposite of weak-mindedness, is also not a mark of intelligence, just the opposite sometimes.

So what does weak-minded really mean and does it indeed imply that the someone described that way might be unintelligent?

Comment: The dictionary definition for  *weak-minded* includes both of the meanings you've given. I would've said the opposite was *strong-willed* rather than *stubborn*  -  or *strong-minded* is a valid option, though I can't say I've encountered it often.

Comment: When one is always right then one may safely be stubborn and intelligent.

Comment: It reads as though you're confusing 'weak-minded', which does broadly mean 'stupid', with 'weak-willed' broadly means 'easily swayed.'

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: would you agree most people would not call a mentally subnormal child "weak-minded" -- seems to me a characterization of an adult and is more of a character flaw than an organic condition like brain damage or developmentally disabled.

Comment: No, I would not agree at all; not for one minute. I think the only reason people would not call a mentally subnormal child 'weak-minded' would be out of compassion or political correctness. 'Mentally subnormal' and 'weak-minded' are so clearly synonymous it's any difference that needs justification, not similarity.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Interesting. It may simply be an old-fashioned term for I barely encounter it applied to adults or children. Would you call an animal that was unintelligent weak-minded?

Comment: No, it's not at all old-fashioned, though no-one here can speak to your experience. To the extent animal intelligence could be relevant yes, of course I'd call an unintelligent animal weak-minded. If you wouldn't, why not?

Answer (score 0):

Being "weak-minded" can imply weakness of the will, i.e. a lack of self-control that causes one to act against one's better judgment. (The technical term for this is "akrasia.")

Answer (score 0):

The term "weak-minded" has multiple common meanings that are different. It can mean stupid. It can mean just a little bit stupid. It can mean easily swayed. It can mean passive as opposed to aggressive. Basically any mental defect is grounds to fairly call someone "weak-minded".

Contrast with "stupid", which has only one common meaning. In idiosyncratic slang it can mean "really good" or it can intensify an adjective, eg "stupid big", but adoption of use cases like these is generally isolated and fleeting.

Comment: Weak-minded seems subtly different: Literally never in my life have I heard someone call a mentally handicapped kid "weak-minded" -- euphemisms would be "slow" or "challenged". Weak-minded seems to me to be applied to adults and to me implies a character flaw more than a disability.

Comment: That's about political correctness, not language.